# automatic String to int[] conversion in Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I have a simple POJO:

```
public class Entry {
    private Integer day;
    private String site;
    private int[] cpms;
    ... // getters/setters/constructor
}
```

My log file which i would like to read seems like:

```
{ "day":"1", "site":"google.com", "cpms":"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]"}
```

Jackson converts the String into Integer automatically according to docs. But it is not for field "cpms". What is the best way to read it?
I know that i can define "cpms" in constructor as string and then parse this string doing an array from it like this:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_JAVA_ARRAY_FOR_JSON_ARRAY, true);
this.cpm = objectMapper.readValue(cpms, int[].class);
```

but is there any smart conversion?

Comment: is your `"cpms":"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]"` field exactly like this? If it were to lose the `"` around the array it would work, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Jackson doesn't have any built-in solution for that. Your array is wrapped with quotes, so it's a string. However there are some approaches that may suit you:

## JSON creator

Define a constructor annotated with `@JsonCreator` and then parse the string:

```java
public class Entry {

    private Integer day;
    private String site;
    private int[] cpms;

    @JsonCreator
    public Entry(@JsonProperty("cpms") String cpms) {
        String[] values = cpms.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
        this.cpms = Arrays.stream(values).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    }

    // Getters and setters
}
```

## Custom deserializer

Write your own deserializer then you can reuse it in other beans:

```java
public class QuotedArrayDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<int[]> {

    @Override
    public int[] deserialize(JsonParser jp, 
                             DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String rawValue = jp.getValueAsString();
        String[] values = rawValue.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
        return Arrays.stream(values).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
    }
}
```

```java
public class Entry {

    private Integer day;
    private String site;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = QuotedArrayDeserializer.class)
    private int[] cpms;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Both solutions looks fine and more nicely than my... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This conversion may also be done using a custom `JsonDeserializer`.

1) Implement a dedicated deserializer class, for example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class IntArrayDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<int[]> {

  public IntArrayDeserializer() {
    super(int[].class);
  }

  @Override
  public int[] deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
                           DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    String arrayAsString = jsonParser.getText();
    if (arrayAsString.length() == 2) { // case of empty array "[]"
      return new int[0];
    }
    String[] strIds = arrayAsString.substring(1, arrayAsString.length() - 1).split(",");
    return Arrays.stream(strIds).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
  }

}
```

2) Add `@JsonDeserialize(using = IntArrayDeserializer.class)` on `Entry.cpms` field.

3) Now the below test should pass:

```
@Test
public void deserializeExample() throws IOException {
  String json = "{ \"day\":\"1\", \"site\":\"google.com\", \"cpms\":\"[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]\"}";
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Entry entry = mapper.readValue(json, Entry.class);
  int[] expected = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
  assertTrue(Arrays.equals(expected, entry.getCpms()));
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that this deserializer is reusable in case there are other fields to convert the same way, it is in line with Jackson API and there is no need to implement ad-hoc work-arounds.